# i want to insert subject id from the subject table into another table with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have the controller php

```
public function storecontact(Request $request)
{
    $img_name=time() .'.' . $request->url->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    $this->validate($request,[
            'content' => 'unique:emails,content,subject'
            
        ]);
    $request->user()->id;
    $email= new Email;
    $email->name=request('name');
    $email->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
 // $email->subject_id = subject()->id;
    $email->email=request('email');
    $email->subject=request('subject');
    $email->hood=request('hood');
    $email->street=request('street');
    $email->content=request('content');
    $email->priority=request('priority');
    $email->url=$img_name;
    $email->status=("ממתין לטיפול");
    $email->subject_id= $subject->id;
  //$email->subject_id= request($id);
  //$email->subject_id=request($id);
    $email->save();
    $request->url->move(public_path('photos'),$img_name);
    return redirect()->back(); 

}
```

this is the subject model realationship

```
 public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
    }
```

and the email model realationship

```
public function subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
}
```

is there any way to insert the subject_id to the emails table?
[image: this is the subject table in the database]

[image: and this is the emails table]

Comment: where the `$subject` variable came from?? and what is your relationship??

Comment: Email model
public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }
}

Subject Model
public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
    }

Comment: how are you getting the subject here?? are you selecting it in the form??

Comment: This is the form

<select class="form-control"  onkeyup="success()" name="subject" id="subject">
                                <option class="" value="עבודה בכביש" id="1">עבודה בכביש</option>
                                <option class="" value="חשמל" id="2">חשמל</option>
                                
                            </select>

Comment: i would suggest you to use the subject id as the option value. and then you can just do `$email->subject_id = $request->subject`

Comment: I tried this but i have to use the option value for another column field

Comment: if the option value is unique, then you can look for the row in the db using that value and then insert that row id in the email

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: add your database schema and your model code in your question..based on that i will add an answer for you

Comment: is there a way to talk to you directly?

Comment: just add details in your question.. that will help to answer your question.